# Add property to object inside function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

Would there be any way, to add another property to this object inside this function (used as a class):

```
function DP() {
    var _this = this;

    this.displayTypes = {
        normal: function(div) { _this.displayNormal(div) },
        round: function(div) { _this.displayRound(div) }
    }

    this.displayNormal = function(div) { ... };
    this.displayRound = function(div) { ... };

    this.display = function(div, type) {
        this.displayTypes[type](div);
    }
}

var dp = new DP();

// Now here I'd basically like to add another property to the DP.displayTypes
// called "rect" referencing to a function in a different class called
// DPExtension.displayRect(). So something like this:
//     rect: function(div) { DPExtension.displayRect(div) }
```

So that I could call a `dp.display("place-to-display", "rect")` and that it would then execute `displayRect("place-to-display")` from the `DPExtension` class/function basically, whilst calling something like `dp.display("place-to-display", "round")` would execute a `displayRound("place-to-display")` from `DP` instead.

How does one do that? I tried doing some things with `prototype` but to no avail...

Comment: If `displayRect` is a method and not just a function, then you need to mention the object it is attached to somewhere in your code.

Comment: If you create another function separate from your `DP` function, (outside it) the `this` value inside that function will refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems like you want changes to `displayTypes` to be shared by all instances of `DP`, you should make it shared by all instances and not instance specific. You could do this by making it a static property of `DP`:

```
function DP() {
    // these should probably go on DP.prototype as well
    this.displayNormal = function(div) { ... };
    this.displayRound = function(div) { ... };
}

// static
DP.displayTypes = {
    normal: function(div) { this.displayNormal(div) },
    round: function(div) { this.displayRound(div) }
};

DP.prototype.display = function(div, type) {
    this.displayTypes[type].call(this, div);
};

DP.prototype.displayTypes = DB.displayTypes;


// somewhere else
DP.displayTypes.rect =  DPExtension.displayRect;
```

You don't have to create a static property all, you could define `displayTypes` directly on the prototype, but extending it via `DB.displayTypes.foo = ...` reads a bit nicer than `DB.prototype.displayTypes.foo = ...`.

Comment: And with his current code `displayTypes` would not be part of `DP.prototype.`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It doesn't have to be on `DP.prototype` to make it shared between instances, but that's the more natural way to do it.

Comment: This worked, thanks for that but can you or someone else explain to me **why** using `prototype` is the better option over defining it inside the `DP` function?

Comment: @jers: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add it like this:

```
var dp = new DP();
dp.displayTypes['rect'] = function(div) { DPExtension.displayRect(div); };
```

Comment: Yes, and that does indeed work, but now you are only modifying the `displayTypes` that is already in `dp`. So if you would say for example make another variable called `second-dp` and equal it `new DP();` it doesn't have the modified `displayTypes` in it, which is what I'm looking for (my apologies if that wasn't made clear enough in the OP).

Comment: Oh, I got it know. Let me think about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change DP to have a display type object when you create DP and pass current instance  of. DP when creating a display type.

Put the methods of DP on DP.prototype. and the methods of DisplayTypes on DisplayTypes.prototype adding methods later would affect all instances, future and already created.

About prototype:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941